# What is the correct syntax for portable fstream file paths?

Tags: c++, file-io, fstream

I have seen this annoying question again and again. Could you please share your knowledge that might help us to find the answer.

My confusion is that, forward-slash is posix standard but directory structure of operating systems are different.

Thank you

### **What is the correct syntax for portable fstream file paths?**

(e.g. the string you would pass to std::fstream:open() to open a file.)

A.    "::directory:file.bin"

B.    "C:/Directory/File.bin"

C.    "/directory/file.bin"

D. "C://Directory//File.bin"

E.    std:fstream file paths are not portable.

Comment: You can adopt the Boost Filesystem library, which makes portable path names available. See https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**E** : not portable, i.e. *implementation defined*

Answer can be found in the [`std::fopen`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fopen) docs: (which are referred to by [fstream](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_fstream/open) via [filebuf::open](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_filebuf/open))

> Notes
>
> The format of filename is implementation-defined, and does not
>   necessarily refer to a file (e.g. it may be the console or another
>   device accessible through filesystem API). On platforms that support
>   them, filename may include absolute or relative filesystem path.

Comment: Answering by referring to documentation is great, thank you very much.

Answer (score 4):

What you and many of the rest of us are eagerly awaiting is the FileSystem Technical Specification: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4099.html

It is largely an import of `boost/filesystem` into the C++ standard.

The technical specification has been made available as part of C++'s `experimental` section. However, that isn't implemented by default in gcc 4.9.2 or Visual Studio 2013.

Here's to hoping it's coming soon!

You can see more information here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/fs

What you are specifically looking for is `path`: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/fs/path

By way of answering your problem in the now though if you're looking to do this you need to use `#ifdef`s and implement your code per target platform.

Answer (score 1):

(E) - there is no portable standard, as different filesystems and Operating Systems have different expectations and restrictions.  `fstream`s don't restrict you to the minimum always-supported subset of all actual implementations, or you'd only be able to write "8.3" filenames to the current working directory ;-P

That said, if you're interested in this "problem space", you'll probably want to check out the [boost filesystem library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm), which is not Standard, but is at least widely known....

Answer (score 0):

Paths are not portable. It is futile to try to use a portable syntax, since any that you come up with may not be portable between future filesystems. However, it should be possible to do one of the following:

1. Design your application so that you do not need to store paths.
2. Use your own path format which you can covert into paths on the current system.
3. Restrict the paths that your application uses to a portable (between Windows/Linux) subset (e.g: relative paths with "/" as path separator)
4. Store multiple versions for the same path and use the correct one on each supported OS.
5. Store one form of paths (e.g. Linux paths) and use a simple scheme to convert to e.g: Windows paths. Document this scheme so that the user understands how paths are interpreted.

I wrote more on this here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40980510/2345997